# adding a div with jquery doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/uWUDP/

the html:

```
<body></body>
```

the js:

```
var width = $(window).width,
    height = $(window).height;

$("body").append("<div>zz</div>");

$("div").attr("width", width);
$("div").attr("height", height);
$("div").style("background", "black");
```

i'd expect there to be a black box the size of the page created. instead there's nothing.

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You didn't select the jQuery library in your fiddle
- jQuery has no `style` method.  Use `.css`
- `div`s have no width/height attribute.  Use the `.width` and `.height` methods.
- `width = $(window).width` assigns the jQuery `.width` method to the width.  You need to call the function with `()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/uWUDP/3/